# EF Core - Discriminator is Guid?

Tags: entity-framework

When a School entity is added to the database, the discriminator is being set to a guid instead of "school".  Subsequent reads where the type is School does not return the new row.  Why is it a Guid?  I don't define/set the discriminator in my code.

Using EF Core 1.1.2 with VS 2017 15.2 with SQL 2016.

Comment: Show the (relevant) classes. And all the mappings etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response and sorry for taking so long to respond.  The project is rather large and difficult to isolate the issue.

The solution was to add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer version 1.1.1 to my project.  Prior to that, the project had no reference to it.

When the project was inserting a guid for a discriminator, I could VS => Debug => Windows => Modules and see that Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll was version 1.00.4.30428 (presumably from a child project).

When the project was inserting the class name for a discriminator (my desired behavior), I could VS => Debug => Windows => Modules and see that Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll was version 1.01.1.30217.

Thanks again.